# I am using gitlab cicd ,job use image to build a binary file. now I want to export this binary file ,but use artifact, it prompt not found this file

Tags: gitlab-ci

The `gitlab-ci.yml` like this. the binary file is in `output` dir

```
before_script:
  - echo $CI_BUILD_REF
  - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  - echo $REPO_NAME
  - rm -rf /home/gitlab-runner/go/src/$REPO_NAME
  - mkdir -p $(go env GOPATH)/src/$REPO_NAME
  - cp -ar $CI_PROJECT_DIR $(go env GOPATH)/src/$(dirname $REPO_NAME)
  - cd $(go env GOPATH)/src/$REPO_NAME
  - export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(go env GOPATH)/src/$REPO_NAME/third_party/libs/amd64

build:
  image: zdlz_go:bionic-3.3
  stage: build
  script:
    - make build
    - ls output
    - ls $CI_BUILDS_DIR
    - pwd
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - output/*
  tags:
    - runner-build
```

CICD log like this

```
$ ls output
qscs-cert-publish--7744983
$ ls $CI_BUILDS_DIR
backend-project
$ pwd
/home/user/go/src/gitlab.zdlz.tech/zdlz/P2023055_QSCS_certificate_system/qscs-cert-publish
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: output/*: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Job succeeded
```

It can be found in scripts, it seems need to mount ?

Comment: i fix it by removing before_script